# prototype - select statement not working for some elements

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a table, it has some checkboxes. I iterate through the rows, and find the checkbox with

```
var chkboxs = row.select('[name="selected"]') // works - get the correct single array, and can see the checkbox
```

On the exact same row, I then look for another element, this one named 'cgi_args' - but it does not work. I am new at prototype, so perhaps its something easy.

```
    var args2 = row.select('[name="cgi_args"]') // returns array of 0 items
```

Here is the row:

```
<tr>
    <div class="the_arguments_for_the_stuff" name="cgi_args" style="display:none;" args="folder=dsome%2Fu%2Fstuf%2FHome&more=sfkjg"></div>
    <td>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected">Select</input>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The "name" attribute is not really valid for a `<div>` so I bet the underlying "querySelectorAll()" is ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks. I also changed the div to a link tag and the arg is now an href, which is what it actually is. All working now.

Answer (score 2):

DIVs don't have `NAME` attributes, use `ID` or `CLASS`. Form fields have `NAME` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I will answer my own question: 
The div I was trying to locate had been thrown out by the html parser in the browser, as there was an invalid character - an '&' (which is not in my original question as I needed to clean it a little for posting).

So from the DOM point of view the div did not exist, and so could not be selected. What I did was select all the divs in the row, and select came back with 3, but a visual count showed 4 in the row. Then I looked more carefully at my div... ran it through a test, etc, found the bad character.